# Type inferencing help in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, computer-science-theory, proofs

How would I proceed with proving these two functions are well typed? I am a bit lost with this question.

```
  let rec reduce f lst u =
     match lst with
     | [] -> u
     | (h::t) -> f h (reduce f t u) 

 let rec forall2 p l1 l2 =
     match (l1,l2) with
     | ([],[]) -> true
     | ([],_) -> false
     | (_,[]) -> false
     | ((h1::t1),(h2::t2)) ->
          (p h1 h2) && (forall2 p t1 t2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "proving a function using a type inference" ?  Do you have an assignment to prove these functions are well-typed by hand ?

Comment: Yes, I need to prove if they are well-typed but I am having a hard time where to start or an example to work off of.

Comment: Start with the bases cases and the types that are known, then go backwards from there.

Comment: Clarify the question based on user comments.

Answer (score 0):

> I won't give a fully-fledged solution since the question looks like an assignment.

To do the type-inference yourself, all you have to do is look at the source and make deductions. Then, from your deductions, deduce more and more types until all types are known, or until you've found a discrepancy.

To get you started:

- In `reduce`, you're pattern-matching `lst` against patterns of type `'a list`. Thus, `lst` must be typed as `'a list`.
- The values after each pattern must have the same type, so `u` has the same type as `f h (reduce f t u)`.

*Et cætera, et cætera...*